# Node.js web Scraper running function multiple times. I only want it to run once

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, web-scraping, cheerio

I am attempting to write ${car}, ${link}, ${price} to a csv file. My current code does that but it runs my functions more then once and I end up with ${car}, ${link} and ${price} 5 separate times in my csv file I only want it once. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('post.csv');

//Write Headers

writeStream.write(`Title,Link,Price \n`)

request('https://bringatrailer.com/bmw/e46/?q=e46', (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);


      //Grabs the title and link of the featured e46 listings off of bring a trailer
       $('.featured-listing-title-link').each((a, title) => {
        const car = $(title).text();
        const link = $(title).attr('href');
      


      //Grabs the prices of the featured e46 listings off of bring a trailer
       $('.featured-listing-meta-value').each((i, value) => {
        const price = $(value).text().replace(/,/,"");

        writeStream.write(`${car}, ${link}, ${price} \n`);
      });
    });

      

       //Write to CSV
        console.log('Scraping Complete...') 
  }
});
```

just for reference this is what I would like my csv file to look like

[image: Target CSV file out come]

Comment: It is only running once but you are looping over elements so maybe that's where the issue is?

Comment: @Andy I tried running `$('.featured-listing-title-link').each((a, title)` and `$('.featured-listing-meta-value').each((i, value)` as separate functions which does solve the problem but that creates a new issue where ${price} is not written to the csv file correctly and is underneath the titles and urls instead of lined up with them in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the DOM structure of this specific website, this is what worked on my end.

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("post.csv");


writeStream.write(`Title,Link,Price \n`);

 request("https://bringatrailer.com/bmw/e46/?q=e46", (error, response, html) => {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

   var counter = 0;
   $(".featured-listing-title-link").each((a, title) => {
  const car = $(title).text();
  const link = $(title).attr("href");
  const pricetag = cheerio.load($(".featured-listing-meta-value")[counter]);
  const price = pricetag.text();
  //Grabs the prices of the featured e46 listings off of bring a trailer
  writeStream.write(`${car}, ${link}, ${price} \n`);
  counter += 2;
});

//Write to CSV
console.log("Scraping Complete...");
}
});
```